# Identifying the probability space - definition clarity

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I am reading the following:

[image]

I would like to write out explicitly what $E_X[\hat{Y} \mid Y = 0, A = a]$. I think the relevant definitions are in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable

I was told that $$E_X[Y^\text{?} \mid Y = 0, A = a] =\frac{1}{(p(X \mid Y = 0 \& A = a) } \int_{X \mid Y=0, A=a} \left (\int_{(Y,A)} p(X, A, Y) \, dA \, dY \right ) \hat{Y} \, dX$$

however I do not quite understand how this is derived. Can someone help explain this?

Here is what I think. Generally $E[X \mid Y] = \frac{1}{p(Y)} \cdot E[X \text{ and } Y]$. The $$\int_{(Y, A)} p(X, A, Y) \, dA \, dY = \int_Y \int_A p(X,A,Y) \, dA \, dY$$ is the marginal density on $X.$ Since we are conditioning on $Y=0$ and $A = A$ then $\hat{Y}$ depends only on the covariates $X$, i.e, a function of $X$. We want to find the expected value that function.

Is the above a correct explanation of what is happening? I will greatly appreciate input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\text{right: } & \operatorname E X = \int\limits_{\mathbb R} xf(x)\,dx \\[10pt]
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{\operatorname E X = \int\limits_{\mathbb R} X f(X)\,dX}
\end{align}
$$
Note: capital $X$ appears in $\operatorname E X$ and lower-case $x$ in the integral.

Capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ are two different things, and without attention to the distinction one cannot make one's way through some logical arguments in probability theory, nor even understand such an expression as $\Pr(X\le x).$

There is such a thing as $\Pr(X\le x\mid A),$ where $A$ is an event.

So there is such a thing as $\Pr(X\le x\mid Y=y),$ since $\big[Y=y\big]$ is an event.

Hence there is also such a thing as the **conditional** distribution of the random variable $X$ **given** the event $\big[Y=y\big].$

So there is such a thing as the **conditional** expected value of the random variable $X$ **given** the event $\big[Y=y\big].$

That is denoted $\operatorname E(X\mid Y=y).$

That quantity depends on what number (lower-case) $y$ is. Let us therefore call it $g(y).$

Then $\operatorname E(X\mid Y)$ is defined as $g(Y),$ where this time we see the capital $Y,$ i.e. the random variable.

Thus $\operatorname E(X\mid Y)$ is a random variable whose value is determined by that of $Y.$

Comment: Hi Michael, I apologize but I do not quite understand what is wrong with what I said. Could you perhaps explicitly point out what is wrong?

Comment: @Nalt : Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $\Pr(X = 1) = 6/13,$ $\Pr(X=2) = 4/13,$ and $\Pr(X=3)=3/13).$ Then we can say $$\Pr(X=x) = \frac{12/13} {x+1}$$ for $x=1,2,3.$ So $$ \operatorname E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^3 x \Pr(X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^3 x \cdot \frac {12/13} {x+1} $$ Notice that capital $X$ is the random variable, and lower-case $x$ is the number that is $1$ in the first term, $2$ in the second, and $3$ in the third, and that the expression $\Pr(X=x)$ cannot be understood without knowing which is which. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. However, I think some more confusions remain in the original question. You refer to something called $\operatorname E[X\text{ and } Y],$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. I don't know what $[X\text{ and }Y]$ is. If $X$ and $Y$ were events rather than random variables, then $[X \text{ and } Y]$ would be their intersection. But then one could speak of its probability, but you refer its expected value.